# How do I reference multiple rows in a CSV for uninstalling software?

Tags: powershell

I have a script that queries AD computers for a software installation in outputs to different .csv files based on if the software is installed, uninstalled, or unknown (unable to ping, RPC server unavailable, etc)

Now that I have a csv with the computers that have software installed, I'm trying to use the `Get-WmiObject` to uninstall the software, but I'm not able to reference the CSV correctly. What am I doing wrong? The .csv is laid out like this:

```
Name
comp1
comp2
comp3
```

Here is the script I basically want to run for each row in the CSV:

```
$computers = Import-Csv C:\Users\AaronGDL\Desktop\CompInstalled.csv

foreach ($Name in $computers) {
    Write-Host $_.Name
    $Remove = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName $Name -Filter "Name >like '%Software%'"
    $Remove.Uninstall()
}
```

Comment: Change `-ComputerName $Name` to `-ComputerName $_.Name` ?

Comment: ..and change `>like` into `-like` and change `'%Software%'` to `'*Software*'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$computers` variable is populated from a CSV that has a `Name` column, so you end up with a collection of PowerShell objects that each have a `Name` property. As such its this property you need to reference to get back each computer name within your `ForEach` loop, so `-ComputerName $Name` needs to become `-ComputerName $Name.name`:

```
$computers = Import-Csv C:\Users\AaronGDL\Desktop\CompInstalled.csv

foreach ($Name in $computers) {
    Write-Host $Name.name
    $Remove = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName $Name.name -Filter "Name >like '%Software%'"
    $Remove.Uninstall()
}
```

Alternatively you could do:

```
foreach ($Name in $computers.name) { .. }
```

And then continue to just reference `$Name` within the loop.